# How can I set the value of a parameter in a Select using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a report using LINQ but having problems.

```
        var AppVersion = Start
            .Select(x => new AppVersionModel
            {
                DateYYMMDD = x.DateYYMMDD,
                Android043 = 
            })
```

What I would like to do is to:

```
 set the value of Android043 to be equal to a 1 here if (x => x.IsAndroid && x.AppVersion == "0.4.3")
```

But I am not sure how to do that.  Can someone give advice to me.

Comment: The result of the Linq expression will be an `IEnumerable<AppVersionModel>` - yet I suspect you just want `AppVersionModel` instead.

Comment: What is the definition of `Start`? Is it an instance or static property or a local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the expression inside parentheses to be unambiguous (though the parentheses are unnecessary)

```
IEnumerable<AppVersionModel> appVersion = Start
    .Select( x => new AppVersionModel
    {
        DateYYMMDD = x.DateYYMMDD,
        Android043 = ( x.IsAndroid && x.AppVersion == "0.4.3" )
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
 var AppVersion = Start
            .Select(x => new AppVersionModel
            {
                DateYYMMDD = x.DateYYMMDD,
                Android043 = (x.IsAndroid && x.AppVersion == "0.4.3") ? 1 : //someothervalue
            });
```